# Create a generic map using type given at runtime

Tags: java, generics, reflection, collections

The title may be a bit hard to understand, but let me just briefly describe my problem.

Let's assume I have an annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Identifier {

}
```

Now, I make a class which annotates **any** of its fields with it:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @Identifier
    private String idNumber;
    ...
}
```

Finally, at runtime I want to create a `Map` with the key type of `typeof(field annotated with @Identifier)` and the value type of `Student`. Note that any field can be annotated with `@Identifier`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Ok, let me clarify this a bit:

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @Identifier
    private String idNumber;
}

class Foo {
    @Identifier
    private Integer x;
}

//  Now, what I want to have are two maps:

SortedMap students;     //  key type: String
                        //  value type: Student
SortedMap foos;         //  key type: Integer
                        //  value type: Foo
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you planning to use the generated `Map`?

Comment: So you want to find all classes annotated with `@Identifier`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Not sure what you mean. What I want to achieve is to be able to run something like `final SortedMap<keyType, valType> map = db.createTreeMap("cieciecierecie");`

Comment: Ok, that's something you won't be able to do. `keyType` will only be determined at run time. So will `valType`. You can create the `Map`, but you can't usefully declare a variable to hold it like that.

Comment: @AdamArold: No, I want to create a `Map` whose key type will be the same as the field which is annotated with `@Identifier` and value type the same as the class which has the annotated field.

Comment: This is clear but in what context will you use this? For example will you have a method which receives an `Object` which may hold a field annotated with `@Identifier`?

Comment: @AdamArold: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Do you need it to be a generic `Map` like `Map<TypeA, TypeB>` or a simple `Map<Object, Object>` will do which holds object with you desired type?

Comment: Generics are erased at run time so the way I've understood what you've asked at the moment, the answer is *"no, you just can't do this"*. It might be possible with unchecked casts if you know the classes at the point you call the `createTreeMap` and can give it Class objects for `K` and `V`. Otherwise perhaps you could clarify what you are really wanting to do here. Do you really need generics?

Comment: The edit doesn't help clarify much to me, sorry. In my comment I pointed to two things: 1) Do you know the classes at the point you call the method to create the map and can give it Class objects? *(possible)* Or are you wanting to return the map generically typed based on whatever is found in the search? *(impossible and frankly ambiguous because what if two different types are found?)* 2) Do you really need generics?

Comment: @Radiodef: No, I don't know the classes at the point of calling the method. And no, I don't really need generics as long as the key is `Comparable` and the value `Serializable`.

Comment: OK I would recommend what the answers are saying then. If you can't hand Class objects in to the method call then there is no way to do this generically and have it be type-safe (type-safe in that the Class objects would allow checks and fail-fast casting).

Comment: I'm confused now as well. You can create a `Map` and put anything you want in it. Your problem seems to be how do you determine a value of the identifier. My solution was using the `Class` object for the `String` class as the key. That doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think they want to, for example, return a `Map<String, Student>` where Students are mapped to idNumbers.

Comment: @Pateman Well both answers show you the basic process. `for(/* all fields */) { if(/* field is annotated */) { /* put stuff in map */ } }` You just have to return a `Map<Object, Object>`, `Map<?, ?>`, or `Map` (raw Map not recommended). Or like a `Map<? extends Comparable<?>, ? extends Serializable>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not exactly sure what you want to do.

> at runtime I want to create a Map with the key type of typeof(field
>   annotated with @Identifier) and the value type of Student

You can create a raw `Map` or a `Map<Object, Object>`. You can get the type of the field annotated with `@Identifier`. I'm not sure what you mean by *value type of Student* so I'll assume you mean the type `Student`, ie. its `Class` object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = Student.class;
    Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        Identifier annotation = field.getAnnotation(Identifier.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            map.put(field.getType(), clazz);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

With your example class in your question, this prints

```
{class java.lang.String=class com.spring.Student}
```

So the annotated field type is mapped to the class type.

You won't be able to have a `Map<String,Student>` though because you don't know the type `String` (and possibly not even `Student`)  at compile time. You can try casting, but you're setting yourself up for a number of `ClassCastException`s.

Comment: @Pateman I'm not sure that my current solution does what you want it to do.

Comment: No, it doesn't, but the last part of your answer states that what I'm looking for is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

So you are going to have a method (`myMethod` in my example) which will be passed objects which may hold a field annotated with `@Identifier`.

Sorry to burst your bubble but there is no way to keep generic information at runtime. The closest you can get is having a `Map<Field, Class<?>>` which holds key-value pairs with your desired type. This is how you do it:

```
public Map<Field, Class<?>> myMethod(Object obj) {
    Map<Field, Class<?>> result = new HashMap<Field, Class<?>>();
    for(Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        Identifier identifier = field.getAnnotation(Identifier.class);
        if(identifier != null) {
            result.put(field, obj.getClass());
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In my example the result will either be an empty `Map` or a `Map` with one key-value pair. I suggest you should use a separate type for the result instead of a `Map`. Of course you can tamper with the code if you want something other than a `Field` for example you can use `Field`'s `getType()` or `getGenericType()` methods.